# Equal paddings between 3*n items in a 3 column layout?

Tags: css, padding

I want to implement a 3 column layout using the `flex` property, like this:

```
item-----item-----item
```

Where the `-----` represents the padding between each item. Now, the problem is that while these rules:

```
.col-3-grid .grid-item {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.col-3-grid .grid-item:nth-of-type(2n) {
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

.col-3-grid .grid-item:nth-of-type(3n) {
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

Work for the first line of the layout, if I have 5 of `.grid-item` or 4, or even more than 3, it breaks and it looks something like this:

```
item--item-----item
```

The space is uneven, because my rules can't pick up that "Okay, it's end of the row, reset rules", due to it applying `.col-3-grid .grid-item:nth-of-type(2n)` rule to my `4th` item, which as per the code, is a just appliance.

But how can I tell it to apply the right paddings?

Comment: Since you just want to space the content evenly, why not use `justify-content: space-between`?

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao Great call! For everyone reading, Check Anurag's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using flex box, may I suggest using the `justify-content: space-between` attribute. It will adjust itself for any number of `.grid-items`.

```css
.col-3-grid,
.col-4-grid,
.col-5-grid {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 15vw;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3-grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Block1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Block2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Block3</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-4-grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Block1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Block2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Block3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Block4</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-5-grid">
  <div class="grid-item">Block1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Block2</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Block3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Block4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">Block5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great one, great answer. Here's how I implemented mine though: I gave each grid-item a `flex: 0 0 32%` and set a `max-width: 33.3333%` (for the 3-columns) and used `justify-content: space-between;` for the big container. This works seamlessly!

Comment: Another question - I understand the need to specify a height, but is it really needed in my context? The content is dynamic.

Comment: AFAIK, not unless you are going for `column/column-reverse`. Only width should suffice for default case